# request.login() in Java EE 7?

Tags: java, http, servlets, authentication, java-7

Is there a `request.login()` method in Java EE7? I keep getting a:

> `The method login(String, String) is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest`

even though i have all the correct `import` packages.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
```

I'm trting to implement [programmatic login](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html) to access a protected page from an unprotected page. My system is using Java 7 but the example I found is going off of Java 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HttpServletRequest#login`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is only available in Servlet spec 3.0 or greater. Ensure that youre using a jar file that complies with this version and that the servlet container (e.g. Tomcat 7 or higher) supports the functionality for this version.

Comment: @bob_bingo Servlets 3.0 works with Java EE 6 with no problems.

Comment: @Luiggi Thanks...I'm using Java 7

Comment: @bob_bingo but you're not using Servlets 3.0 nor Servlets 3.1, which makes me wonder if you're really using Java EE 7. Note that using an application server that is Java EE 7 compliant doesn't mean you're using Java EE 7.

Comment: @Luiggi My system is using Java 7 but I am going off a Java 6 example...See link in question

Comment: @Reimeus where would I find what version of Servlet I'm using in my Java files?

Comment: The jar will be on the classpath for your project. It will be something obvious like `javax.servlet-2.5.jar` or if youre using Maven the dependency version will be in your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is in fact a `login` function in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Java 7 comes with [Servlet 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven try with the following dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```